# Yammer API - Follow person

Tags: yammer

How to follow a person using yammer API?
I know there is follow button provided by Yammer embed but that has its own styling.

Tried creating open graph activity using following code, but this creates an activity and open graph page but does not reflect in "Following" for the specified user.

> yam.platform.getLoginStatus(function (response) {

```
            if (response.authResponse) {
                yam.platform.request({
                    url: "activity.json",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {
                        "activity": {
                            "actor": {
                                "name": "Kavleen Kaur",
                                "email": "Kavleen.Kaur@abc.com"
                            },
                            "action": "follow",
                            "object": {
                             "url": "https://www.yammer.com/abc.com/users/username",
                                "title": "Testing follow Activity!",
                                "type":"person"
                                                                },
                            "message": "Testing follow activity from JS SDK!"
                        }
                    },
                    success: function (msg) { alert("Post was Successful!: " + msg); },
                    error: function (msg) { console.dir(msg); }
                })
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks kendomen for your reply! However, I got unauthorized error due to CORS. Got it to work using following:

```
yam.platform.request(
   {
       url: "subscriptions"
       , method: "POST"
       , data: {
           target_type: "user",
           target_id: item.SENDERID
       }
       , success: function (msg) {
           alert('Followed');
       }
       , error: function (msg) { }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow a person like this.

```
function follow(sender_id) {
        yam.request(
          { url: "https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/subscriptions"
              , method: "POST"
              , data: {
                  target_type: "user",
                  target_id: sender_id
              }
              , success: function (msg) {

              }
              , error: function (msg) {  }
        });
    }
```